# rtcmulticonnection safari apple mac

Tags: safari, webrtc

I have my own rtcmulticonnection server up and running

I found this plugin https://github.com/muaz-khan/PluginRTC

But it doesn't seems to work

> I get WebRTC 1.0 (RTCPeerConnection) API are NOT available in this
>   browser.

here my code (working in chrome and firefox but not in safari)

```
<div id="videos-container"></div>

<script src="js/rmc3.min.js').'"></script>
<script src="js/socket.io.js').'"></script>
<script src="js/Plugin.EveryWhere.js').'"></script>

<script>  

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
connection.socketURL = "https://__MyDomain.com:9000/";
var roomid = "main_room";

connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};

var videosContainer = document.getElementById("videos-container");
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    videosContainer.appendChild(event.mediaElement);
    setTimeout(function() { event.mediaElement.play();  }, 5000);
};

connection.openOrJoin(roomid);

// *** Plugin.EveryWhere.js [BEGIN]
var Plugin = {};
window.onPluginRTCInitialized = function(pluginRTCObject) {
    Plugin = pluginRTCObject;
    MediaStreamTrack      = Plugin.MediaStreamTrack;
    RTCPeerConnection     = Plugin.RTCPeerConnection;
    RTCIceCandidate       = Plugin.RTCIceCandidate;
    RTCSessionDescription = Plugin.RTCSessionDescription;
};
if (!!window.PluginRTC) window.onPluginRTCInitialized(window.PluginRTC);

connection.onaddstream = function(event) {
    if (isPluginRTC) {
        var mediaElement = document.createElement("videos-container");

        var body = (document.body || document.documentElement);
        body.insertBefore(mediaElement, body.firstChild);

        setTimeout(function() {
            Plugin.attachMediaStream(mediaElement, event.stream);

            // here you can append "mediaElement" to specific container
            // specificContainer.appendChild(mediaElement);
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        // do chrome/Firefox relevant stuff with "event.stream"
    }
};
// *** Plugin.EveryWhere.js [END]

</script>
```

Is someone was able to make the plugin work ?
If yes how or what step did I missed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

RTCMultiConnection-v3.2.95 **now supports** IE/Safari:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/releases/tag/3.2.95

To support Safari/IE, please modify [Gruntfile.js#L30](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L30) to enable [`dev/Plugin.EveryWhere.js`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/dev/Plugin.EveryWhere.js).

Then don't forget calling `grunt` to recompile the codes.

Now set `connection.trickleIce=false` in your HTML file. And now video-conferencing/chat/etc. will work both among chrome/firefox/safari/IE.

Please install [PluginRTC.dmg](http://dl.webrtc-experiment.com/PluginRTC.dmg) or [PluginRTC.exe](http://dl.webrtc-experiment.com/PluginRTC.exe).

#### Additional notes:

1. You've to initiate calls from Safari/IE, because currently Safari/IE can not create answers. i.e. IE/Safari MUST call `connection.open` instead of calling `connection.join`.
2. Set this in your HTML: `connection.processSdp = function(sdp) {return sdp;};` to prevent SDP conflicts/errors.

Comment: I did the update and instsalled the safari plugin and applied the connection.open AND connection.trickleIce=false *** but I still get WebRTC 1.0 (RTCPeerConnection) API are NOT available in this browser. see the pic of the safari console : https://gyazo.com/ecdb153573600092d42d2903941a2d11

Comment: You seems using old rmc3.min.js Please make sure that it is 3.2.95 or greater.